# Django Admin: Link to Admin-Interface of ForeignKey beneath add and modify

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django model called `Foo`

IT has ForeignKey to "Remote".

This gets displayed like this in the django admin:

[image]

There are two icons beneath the drop-down: "modify" and "add".

It would be very cool if I could have a third icon: A link to the admin page of the given Remote instance.

How could this be done?

Some kind of re-usability would be nice, since I want this feature for several admin pages.

Comment: The edit icon already links to the admin of the given foreign key, albeit in a popup... or do you just want a third icon in general?

Comment: I want a third icon that does not open a pop-up. Just a normal link would be nice.

Comment: I posted an answer to this, if you still need it.

Comment: Overwrite the admin template then add some JS at the bottom which listens for the dropdown changing. Each dropdown option has the pk in the "value" attribute so you can then add a link which takes you to the edit/pk page on the admin panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't personally tested this but to add more icons you should be able to accomplish that by overwriting the admin template for the widget for `related_widget_wrapper`.

See these two files:

[django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/related_widget_wrapper.html](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/related_widget_wrapper.html)
[django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/related_widget_wrapper.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/related_widget_wrapper.html)

Specifically, you'd want to this to generate the change url: `{{ change_related_template_url }}` without the `{{ url_params }}`

Overriding admin templates:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

Answer (score 1):

There's a start code to help you

1 - First you need use javascript to work dynamic elements, so you can use some like this:

```
$('a.related-widget-wrapper-link add-related, a#add_id_client').after('<a href="#" class="float-right"> <img src="/static/application/img/avatar.jpg"> </a>');
```

Note: `a#add_client`, change to your current model name

[image: Dynamic Element JS]

2 - Set your url to `<a href=""></a>` in javascript

3 - Finally, link you .js code to your template, using `class Meta:` or overwriting `base.html`. e.g:

**base.html** end file

```
    {% block footer %}
    {% endblock %}

</div>
<!-- END Container -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "application/js/my_custom_javascript.js"%}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```